# Sending a variable from express middleware to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I have a keystonejs app setup, using express and jade.

I have a fullscreen background image setup in my default.jade file which defines various imports and also the header and footer of the site.

I am trying to rotate the image based on a selection of images that are located in the mongodb via mongoose.

I was having issues getting it to work, so i have just been trying to get the variable to print correctly in the header of my page.

I have the following code setup in my root middleware file, as part of the export.initLocals file:

```
    exports.initLocals = function(req, res, next) {

    var locals = res.locals;

    locals.navLinks = [
        { label: 'Home',        key: 'home',        href: '/' },
        { label: 'News',        key: 'blog',        href: '/news' },
        { label: 'Creations',   key: 'creation',    href: '/creations' },
        { label: 'Contact',     key: 'contact',     href: '/contact' }
    ];

    locals.user = req.user;

    locals.imageURL = 'variable set';

    WelcomeImage = keystone.list('WelcomeImage');

    WelcomeImage.model.findOneRandom(function(err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                locals.imageURL = result.Image.url;
                console.log(result.Image.url); // 1 element 
            } else {
                console.log(err); // 1 element
            }
    });

    next();

};
```

and within my default.jade file i have:

```
//- HTML BODY
    body

        #background-image

        //- HEADER
        #header: .container

            //- Customise your site's navigation by changing the navLinks Array in ./routes/middleware.js
            //- ... or completely change this header to suit your design.

            div(role="navigation").navbar.navbar-default
                .container-fluid
                    .navbar-header
                        .visible-xs.navbar-brand-xs.a(href='/')
                            img(align:"left",src="/images/wild_logo.png",border=0,width=45,height=45)
                        button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
                            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
                            span.icon-bar
                            span.icon-bar
                            span.icon-bar
                    .collapse.navbar-collapse
                        .hidden-xs.navbar-brand.a(href='/')
                            img(align:"left",src="/images/wild_logo.png",border=0,width=95,height=95)
                        ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left
                            each link in navLinks
                                li(class=(section == link.key ? 'active' : null)): a(href=link.href)= link.label
                        ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                            if user
                                if user.canAccessKeystone
                                    li: a(href='/keystone') Open Keystone
                                li: a(href='/keystone/signout') Sign Out
                            else

                            if imageURL
                                | #{imageURL}
                            else
                                There is no variable
                                //li: a(href='/keystone/signin') Sign In

        //- BODY
        #body
```

Now every time i load the page i see the variable rendered in the page, but it is set as 'variable set' and never get's set to the actual URL.

Now if i watch the console, the correct value is sent to the console on the line directly after it's set on locals.

So, any ideas what i'm doing wrong. I'm very new to express/jade so it's likely i'm overlooking something in the order things are done?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Gareth

Comment: Try moving `next()` inside the callback function of the `findOneRandom` call. You're basically telling node it's safe to move on before the callback is complete.

Comment: That's sorted it, thanks. Add it as an answer below and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `next()` inside the callback function of the `findOneRandom` call. You're basically telling node it's safe to move on before the callback is complete.

Glad that helped. Thanks!